# Why are some OpenSSH CVE patches not being updated when checking for updates?

Tags: cve, openssh

I am working to pass some Trustwave PCI scans on my server, starting with the OpenSSH CVEs.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
root@host [~]# ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
root@host [~]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-042stab116.2 (root@kbuild-rh6-x64.eng.sw.ru) (gcc version 4                 .4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jun 24 15:33:57 MSK 2016
```

I have been grepping through the changelog to confirm that certain CVE issues have the appropriate patches installed. I've been able to confirm the following have been addressed:

```
root@host [~]# rpm -q --changelog openssh | grep 'CVE'

 - CVE-2016-3115: missing sanitisation of input for X11 forwarding (#1317817)
 - CVE-2016-1908: Prevent possible fallback from untrusted X11 forwarding (#1299048)
 -  CVE-2015-5352: XSECURITY restrictions bypass under certain conditions
 -  CVE-2015-5600: MaxAuthTries limit bypass via duplicates in KbdInteractiveDevices
 -  CVE-2015-6563: Privilege separation weakness related to PAM support
 -  CVE-2015-6564: Use-after-free bug related to PAM support
 - prevent a server from skipping SSHFP lookup (#1081338) CVE-2014-2653
 - ignore environment variables with embedded '=' or '\0' characters CVE-2014-2532
 - change default value of MaxStartups - CVE-2010-5107 - #908707
 - fixed audit log injection problem (CVE-2007-3102)
 - CVE-2006-5794 - properly detect failed key verify in monitor (#214641)
 - CVE-2006-4924 - prevent DoS on deattack detector (#207957)
 - CVE-2006-5051 - don't call cleanups from signal handler (#208459)
 - use fork+exec instead of system in scp - CVE-2006-0225 (#168167)
```

However, the following CVEs - which are showing up as vulnerabilities in the scan - are not showing up in the change log.

CVE-2015-8325

CVE-2016-10009

CVE-2016-10012

CVE-2016-0777

CVE-2016-10010

CVE-2016-6515

All of this after:

```
root@host [~]# yum update

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Setting up Update Process

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

 * base: mirrors.liquidweb.com

 * centosplus: centos.mirrors.my2pro.com

 * contrib: mirrors.tummy.com

 * epel: mirror.compevo.com

 * extras: repo1.sea.innoscale.net

 * fasttrack: mirror.scalabledns.com

 * updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net

No Packages marked for Update
```

Everything I'm reading online is saying do NOT update OpenSSH to the latest version, since everything should be backported. However, it seems to me that the version I am running is not getting updated with the appropriate patches.

Should I be manually installing these patches, or should I just try installing the latest version of openssh?

Comment: I recommend that you look at each of these CVE at the announcement for you distribution. For example CVE-2015-8325 is [marked as nofix](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2015-8325) for RHEL 6 and RHEL 5 since  a [very unlikely non-default configuration](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1328012#c3) is needed to the bug have any effect. It's probably similar for the other CVE or maybe they don't apply to the relevant SSH version at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be manually installing these patches, or should I just try installing the latest version of openssh?

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

The important CVEs are in the package already fixed, as you found out. The others might not be, because they are not exploitable in the supported configuration or the effects are not severe. This is why the CVE numbers have their descriptions and impact. If you search around, you will see the explanation why it was or was not backported to RHEL6.

Updating OpenSSH to current version might make sense in some cases, but the interoperability with the rest of the system can be broken, you can get worse user experience or security in some cases. You will also not get any more bugfix and security updates from Red Hat. In this case you would need to follow the upstream releases, update manually and possibly add the patches that are used in Red Hat OpenSSH package to get similar user experience and security.